# .Net 4.0 parallel - how to know when task is finished

Tags: .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I have a Tasks table. Tasks are added to this table all the time. After task is finished, I should delete it from the table and perform some other operations. The tasks should be executed concurrently. If I use Task class (Task.Factory.StartNew...), how can I know when Task is finished, in order to perform some operations regarding to it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can *test* for completion with `Task.IsCompleted`. You can *wait* for a task to be completed with `Task.Wait` (or a variant). You can tell a task to do something else afterwards with `Task.ContinueWith`. The last one here may well be what you want here.

Comment: Definitely consider chaining tasks with ContinueWith - it should simplify your life immensely.